# Hash function with values in a multiplicative group of prime order

Tags: hash, random-oracle-model

I have to implement a cryptographic protocol which involves a cryptographic hash function $H: \{0,1\}^* \to G$. It is viewed as random oracle. $G$ is a multiplicative group of prime order.

I want to know the steps to implement this function. Are there standard functions to do this?

The protocols also have pairing operations. It would be helpful if you could shed some light on their implementation too.

Comment: There are (at least) two different meanings to 'G is a multiplicative group'?  Do you mean that it's a prime-ordered subgroup of $Z^*_p$, for some prime $p$?  Or, is it some group which happens to be expressed in multiplicative notation (that is, the group operation is written $A \times B = C$)?

Comment: The other obvious question is "do you care if you can deduce the relationship between the hashes of various strings?  For example, if $A = hash("foo")$, and $B = hash("bar")$, do you care if someone can compute $n$ with $nA = B$?  If you don't care (and whether you do or not will depend on what you're doing with this hash function), then there's an easy solution for any finite group.

Comment: which group are you using?

Comment: Reading "The protocols also have pairing operations", I would guess that you are asking about the "hash to curve" problem. Did I get this right ?